# Navigation Bar in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have application and I'm using ActionBar. In every activity I'm using navigation button which takes me back to parent activity. Now I would like to add similar button in main activity which activate menu (the same action is implemented in Gmail Android Application).

Main Activity in Gmail application:

[image: Main Activity in Gmail application]

Main Activity in Gmail application after using navigation (menu) button in left top corner:

[image: Main Activity in Gmail application after using navigation (menu) button in left top corner]

Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: do you mean to open  `NavigationDrawer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sliding menu is called Navigation Drawer.
Check this for a guide and sample app: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

In that link explains how to configure the Action Bar and the menu itself.

UPDATE:
To handle click in that specific button you have to add this in your

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method:

```
if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))  
{
     // Your code.
     return true;
}
```

You can find more about the object drawerToggle in the link I provided.
Good luck.

Comment: Could you tell me one more think? Do you know how to just exit the application after touch to this button (instead opening menu)?

Comment: OK, it looks nice, but what if I don't need menu any more? Now I have to create DrawerLayout etc, but if I want just to leave application after pressing button, can I do it without creating so many new object which will be exackly not used?

Comment: Oh, not at all. You can check if the item id is android.R.id.home or similar (I can't check it right now).

Comment: And this is exackly what I need

Answer (score 1):

Please read this training [post](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Download and investigate sample attached to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the navigation drawer it's the object that you search